# Create WordPress posts from JSON array using plugin in admin

Tags: ajax, json, wordpress, admin

I'm writing a WordPress plugin that I'd like to do the following:

1. Add a WordPress plugin admin page that contains a button
2. When you click the button, it loads an array of JSON objects from a file, then creates a WordPress post for each object

I got #1 done, and I can see the array of JSON objects loading upon button click since I use console.log. (I made the button using this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pO-FYVZv94#at=2164 -- uses AJAX.)

But, how would I go about giving WordPress access to the JSON array so I can create posts using wp_insert_posts? Is this even possible?

Comment: Set up an action hook using [wp_ajax_{action}](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)). Send the JSON array via POST, and process the information in your callback. Loop through each item in the processed array and use wp_insert_posts to add the new items.

Comment: @maiorano84 `Send the JSON array via POST`
Could you elaborate?

Comment: Read up on [jQuery's AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to gain a better understanding on how to pass your information to the server. Once you have a better idea on how everything works, show us your code and describe what you've tried, and we'll be able to help you.